# Reduce Peak Memory Usage With @autoreleasepool

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nsautoreleasepool

I work on an iPad application that has a sync process that uses web services and Core Data in a tight loop. To reduce the memory footprint according to [Apple's Recomendation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4) I allocate and drain an `NSAutoreleasePool` periodically. This currently works great and there are no memory issues with the current application. However, I plan on moving to ARC where the `NSAutoreleasePool` is no longer valid and would like to maintain this same kind of performance. I created a few examples and timed them and **I am wondering what is the best approach, using ARC, to acheive the same kind of performance and maintain code readability**.

For testing purposes I came up with 3 scenarios, each create a string using a number between 1 and 10,000,000. I ran each example 3 times to determine how long they took using a Mac 64 bit application with the Apple LLVM 3.0 compiler (w/o gdb -O0) and XCode 4.2. I also ran each example through instruments to see roughly what the memory peak was.

Each of the examples below are contained within the following code block:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

        //Code Example ...

        NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceNow];
        printf("Duration: %f\n", interval);
    }
}
```

---

**NSAutoreleasePool Batch [Original Pre-ARC] (Peak Memory: ~116 KB)**

```
    static const NSUInteger BATCH_SIZE = 1500;
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    for(uint32_t count = 0; count < MAX_ALLOCATIONS; count++)
    {
        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", count + 1U];
        [text class];

        if((count + 1) % BATCH_SIZE == 0)
        {
            [pool drain];
            pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        }
    }
    [pool drain];
```

> **Run Times:**
>   *10.928158
>
>   10.912849
>
>   11.084716*

---

**Outer @autoreleasepool (Peak Memory: ~382 MB)**

```
    @autoreleasepool {
        for(uint32_t count = 0; count < MAX_ALLOCATIONS; count++)
        {
            NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", count + 1U];
            [text class];
        }
    }
```

> **Run Times:**
>
>   *11.489350
>
>   11.310462
>
>   11.344662*

---

**Inner @autoreleasepool (Peak Memory: ~61.2KB)**

```
    for(uint32_t count = 0; count < MAX_ALLOCATIONS; count++)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", count + 1U];
            [text class];
        }
    }
```

> **Run Times:**
>
>   *14.031112
>
>   14.284014
>
>   14.099625*

---

**@autoreleasepool w/ goto (Peak Memory: ~115KB)**

```
    static const NSUInteger BATCH_SIZE = 1500;
    uint32_t count = 0;

    next_batch:
    @autoreleasepool {
        for(;count < MAX_ALLOCATIONS; count++)
        {
            NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", count + 1U];
            [text class];
            if((count + 1) % BATCH_SIZE == 0)
            {
                count++; //Increment count manually
                goto next_batch;
            }
        }
    }
```

> **Run Times:**
>
>   *10.908756
>
>   10.960189
>
>   11.018382*

The `goto` statement offered the closest performance, but it uses a `goto`. Any thoughts?

**Update:**

*Note: The `goto` statement is a normal exit for an @autoreleasepool as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW8) and will not leak memory.*

> On entry, an autorelease pool is pushed. On normal exit (break,
>   return, goto, fall-through, and so on) the autorelease pool is popped.
>   For compatibility with existing code, if exit is due to an exception,
>   the autorelease pool is not popped.

Comment: Use the optimizer. It's rather important for ARC code.

Comment: So that `goto` is definitely not, I don't know, causing a memory leak? Everything else makes sense: less draining is faster. Anyway, I can only comment on readability: anywhere you pool is fine. That goto would need a yellow sticky note.

Comment: The goto did not seem to leak any memory. Looks like the scope drained the autorelease pool as I expected but I am no expert on ARC (yet) and do not want to rely on UB.

Comment: can't you do the same thing by inverting your code and putting the autorelease pool INSIDE the `for` that checks your batch size? Obviously `count` would have to start from where it last left off...

Comment: @Yar Thanks, lack of sleep has me overcomplicating things again.

Comment: I slept almost 36 hours before writing that comment, so I had a definite advantage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should achieve the same thing as the `goto` answer without the `goto`:

```
for (NSUInteger count = 0; count < MAX_ALLOCATIONS;)
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < BATCH_SIZE && count < MAX_ALLOCATIONS; j++, count++)
        {
            NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", count + 1U];
            [text class];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, long day, simple enough answer :).

Comment: This should be up voted more as it's exactly the solution to get the same behaviour as manual draining with the old `NSAutoreleasePool`!

Answer (score 2):

Note that ARC enables significant optimizations which are not enabled at `-O0`. If you're going to measure performance under ARC, you **must** test with optimizations enabled. Otherwise, you'll be measuring your hand-tuned retain/release placement against ARC's "naive mode".

Run your tests again with optimizations and see what happens.

**Update**: I was curious, so I ran it myself. These are the runtime results in Release mode (-Os), with 7,000,000 allocations.

```
arc-perf[43645:f803] outer: 8.1259
arc-perf[43645:f803] outer: 8.2089
arc-perf[43645:f803] outer: 9.1104

arc-perf[43645:f803] inner: 8.4817
arc-perf[43645:f803] inner: 8.3687
arc-perf[43645:f803] inner: 8.5470

arc-perf[43645:f803] withGoto: 7.6133
arc-perf[43645:f803] withGoto: 7.7465
arc-perf[43645:f803] withGoto: 7.7007

arc-perf[43645:f803] non-ARC: 7.3443
arc-perf[43645:f803] non-ARC: 7.3188
arc-perf[43645:f803] non-ARC: 7.3098
```

And the memory peaks (only run with 100,000 allocations, because Instruments was taking forever):

```
Outer: 2.55 MB
Inner: 723 KB
withGoto: ~747 KB
Non-ARC: ~748 KB
```

These results surprise me a little. Well, the memory peak results don't; it's exactly what you'd expect. But the run time difference between `inner` and `withGoto`, even with optimizations enabled, is higher than what I would anticipate.

Of course, this is somewhat of a pathological micro-test, which is very unlikely to model real-world performance of any application. The takeaway here is that ARC may indeed some amount of overhead, but you should always measure your actual application before making assumptions.

(Also, I tested @ipmcc's answer using nested for loops; it behaved almost exactly like the `goto` version.)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the tip. Wasn't aware that additional steps were taken but makes absolute since. Is there an optimization guide similar to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html ? Not expecting to find exact flags but more along the lines of what kind of optimizations may take place. I found some useful attribute items [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#optimization) but it does not look like it is compiler optimization dependent.

Comment: I added some real-world testing with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance in checking the statistics with optimizations. This will be useful for deciding which method to use in the future for various purposes (excluding the `goto` thanks to ipmcc's answer). Hopefully some more people will come through and upvote.