# CPU usage shooting up when I am running a for-in loop: OS-x app

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, cpu, cpu-usage

When my loop runs for about 15k times too much CPU is being used. It's in the range of 90 -100 % always. What I am doing inside the loop is a series of Core data entity updating/creation. Why does that happen? I am running my process in background and I have specified the thread priority to minimum value too!

Comment: If no other processes require significant CPU time then it is perfectly normal for a background process to take 90 - 100%. If you want to make the background process less intrusive then put a `sleep()` call in the for loop

Comment: thanks man! anyway it's not hanging the UI. So let it be like that only :)

Answer (score 2):

Paul R is correct - the system will achieve the tasks in the loop as quickly as possible given the resources it has. In this case, it is manipulating Core Data objects in the Managed Object Context and not committing to disk so the only limitation to how fast it can execute is CPU Time.

Is this causing a UI thread issue? Theoretically, if the UI thread wants CPU time, it should take it. The sleep() would fix that, but is inideal because your background task would take longer to complete.

If so, is there a way to break out the work so it can be more simply chunked than a 15k item loop?

Is something in the loop running using mutex / @synchronise? This can cause a delay before it will ramp down it's CPU-time when requested which can translate to laggy UI.

Comment: It's not hanging the UI. But I was also planning to implement chunking data. May be it can solve the issue to some extent. Thanks for the suggestion!